# I need to generate a token in order to share an 'invite' link, what should the token be?

Tags: token, access-token

Just to elaborate a bit more:

- User A owns a directory of files on my server
- User A wants to share a link with a token that grants **anyone with the link** access to that directory
- I have an API user A can hit (`GenerateDirectoryToken`)
- User A sends this to user B so user B can 'claim' the token (passes this token to the `ClaimDirectoryToken` endpoint)

My understanding is that it would be a bad idea, security-wise, to generate a `GUID` as the token, in which case - **what should I use?** More specifically, what length of string, what array of characters etc.

Comment: WRT, *'My understanding is that it would be a bad idea, security-wise, to generate a GUID as the token'* - what is this understanding based on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GUID, it's even a good idea. Just make sure your GUID generator is using a cryptographically secure random number generator. And for this application I would recommend using UUID v4.

You can use simple table for that, with 16 alphanumeric chars for the token, the full path of the file, and an expiration date.

When someone tries to access the file, you search for the token on the table and see if it's valid or expired. If it's valid, you output the file. if the token has expired, you deny access and delete the token record from the table.

Your API should have a `RevokeDirectoryToken` too, so the user could revoke a token before it expired. He could expire passing a token, or a directory, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Any amount of string that you would like to generate will heavily affect the CPU compute in generating the token if you're considering availability for your infrastructure.

However, Considering your Scenario, I would be using a 6 to an 18-character string that combines numbers and alphabets. For example, You can utilize Python's "**secrets**" module or Java's '**SecureRandom**' Module as they are cryptography libraries/modules designed to generate and assign random strings by default.

Also, I'm not sure but you haven't mentioned if you're going to keep the token persistent or if this would be one-time token accessibility. Perhaps that would provide more clarity for your question.